# Phoenix-Elixir assigns not available in eex template during test

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm in the middle of learning the Elixir using the Phoenix web framework. I've gotten pretty far on my own, but I'm running into an error during a test that has me stumped. The error only occurs during testing, not when actually running the app.

**Error:**

```
  1) test does not create resource and renders errors when data is invalid (Potion.CommentControllerTest)
     test/controllers/comment_controller_test.exs:25
     ** (ArgumentError) assign @num_approved_comments not available in eex template.
```

**comment_controller_test.exs**

```
defmodule Potion.CommentControllerTest do
  use Potion.ConnCase

  alias Potion.Comment
  alias Potion.Factory

  @valid_attrs %{author: "Some Person", body: "This is a sample comment"}
  @invalid_attrs %{}

  setup do
    user = Factory.create(:user)
    post = Factory.create(:post, user: user)
    comment = Factory.create(:comment, post: post)

    {:ok, conn: conn, user: user, post: post, comment: comment}
  end

  test "does not create resource and renders errors when data is invalid", %{conn: conn, post: post} do
    conn = post conn, post_comment_path(conn, :create, post), comment: @invalid_attrs
    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Oops, something went wrong"
  end

  # privates
  defp login_user(conn, user) do
    post conn, session_path(conn, :create), user: %{username: user.username, password: user.password}
  end

end
```

Comment: links to code references are 404

Comment: Downvote because at the current state of this post, no one can learn from it. There is only an error message, the links are dead and the relevant code should be pasted there.  Tracked down the [commit](https://github.com/wsharp07/potion/commit/3702dd2375a9ef7596582fcd381fe7e6a13170bd#diff-8b20332aac23729abaa2b399ce016f2d) that is probably relevant, but if you decide to delete the project, this is lost too.

Comment: Agreed. In retrospect placing the code instead of a link would have been more useful. I added the code snippet from the test, but ultimately it may be better just to delete this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test that is failing is testing the create action of the CommentController, not the show action of the PostController.

Your create action does not include the `@num_approved_comments` in assigns:

```
  def create(conn, %{"comment" => comment_params, "post_id" => post_id}) do
    # Find the post and preload nav props
    post = Repo.get!(Post, post_id) |> Repo.preload([:user, :comments])

    # Build the changeset
    changeset = post
      |> build_assoc(:comments)
      |> Comment.changeset(comment_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      # Inserted successfully
      {:ok, _comment} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Comment created successfully!")
        |> redirect(to: user_post_path(conn, :show, post.user, post))
      # Error on insert
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, Potion.PostView, "show.html", post: post, user: post.user,
        comment_changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

Comment: wow, that's embarrassing. I was looking in the wrong spot the whole time. thanks for the help!